# Codefights No implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby

Here is a code:

```
def allLongestStrings(inputArray)
    array = Array.new
    inputArray.each do |i|
        if inputArray[i].length == inputArray.max.length
            array << inputArray[i]
        end
    end
    return array
end

inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"]
```

It says "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" and I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is Ruby code using PHP thinking. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46164155/4265352) below for a Ruby solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Error is here:

```
if i.length == inputArray.max.length # i instead of inputArray[i]
  array << i
end
```

But I suggest to use select:

```
input_array = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"]
max_length = input_array.max.length
input_array.select { |el| el.length == max_length }
#=> ["aba", "vcd", "aba"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Visit the documentation of ruby array https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each

You can see that "i" is not a position of array but the whole element.

Then, the correct code would be:

```
if i.size== inputArray.max.size
  array << i
end
```

It better use **size** than **length** according ruby style guide.
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide